# openbugs generating inital values error

Tags: winbugs, openbugs

I have a model that I can run in winbugs but I get an error in openbugs when loading and generating initial values even when using the same code and the same data.

When loading initial values in both winbugs and openbugs I get the message that the "chain contains uninitalized variables". Then I can successfully generate initial values in winbugs but in openbugs I get the error "error for node Ny[2] of type GraphBinoimial.  Node second argument must be integer valued." My initial values for Ny are Ny=c(4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4).  These seem like integers to me.  Plus these same initial values are accepted in winbugs.

You may be asking yourself, if I can get it work in winbugs why do I care to get it to work in openbugs?  I am most interested in running the whole process through R. I've been trying to do this with R2Winbugs or Brugs (openbugs) but I get errors on initialization with both of these and it even crashes R (I'd never seen the r-bomb before but now I can make it happen repeatedly). I think this is probably for the same reason that I can't run the data manually in openbugs.

Being able to run this through R would greatly reduce the frustration of interacting with win/openbugs especially when running a series of models with different data.

Thanks in advance for your insight.

lg